# UDP сокеты и выделенный IP

Tags: python, сокет, ip, udp

Недавно жизнь связала меня с UDP несколько больше, чем общее понимание разницы `UDP` / `TCP` / `HTTP`, мне пришлось первый раз в жизни начать писать синхронизацию сервера и клиента в одной инди игрушке на python. Для того, чтобы завести это дело я использовал пакет `socket`. Я конечно всегда знал, что в голом `UDP` нет такого понятия как `connection`, сначала я пытался отправить пакет, и сразу же ожидать результата

```py
sock.sendto(b'hi', target)
resp = sock.recv(1028)
```

В этот момент я уже понял, что ничего не понял. Код вроде бы работает, но во мне затоился вопрос, а как сервер будет отвечать мне? Чисто из соображений логики

```py
_, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
sock.sendto(b'accepted', addr)
```

И на мое удивление это работает, конечно запустив это все в интернете а не на локальной сети, я увидел ужасных 0 - 20 пакетов в секунду, что не есть приемлемо для данной задачи. Не буду описывать весь процесс моего брейншторма, но я самостоятельно пришел к выводу, что нужно разделить логику на два потока, и скидывать результат в защищенный список, из которого уже третий поток будет доставать необходимые ему данные. Всё завелось, ура, дело было под утро и я ложусь спать, закрываю глаза и вижу это:

```py
# client.py

while self.running:
  resp = sock.recv(1028)
```

Когда я понял, что это мертвое дело, я продолжил свои исследования, ведь я осознал, что у меня нет выделенного IP, подними я HTTP сервер, из интернета его никто не найдет, в тупую сделать `socket.bind` тоже не получилось, Windows выбрасывает нам эксепшн `OSError: Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен`. И при этом всем, после единственного пакета, который я отправляю на сервер, сервер может получает мой IP и port и затем может использовать его для отправки данных.

```py
# client.py

target = ('x.x.x.x', 8080)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.settimeout(1.0)

# `Connection` for send ip:port
sock.sendto(b'hi', target)

while True:
    try:
        req = sock.recv(1028)
        print(req)

    except socket.timeout:
        continue
```

```py
# server.py

target  = ('x.x.x.x', 8080)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind(target)

i = 0
last = time()
print("Waiting message...")
_, addr = sock.recvfrom(1028)

while True:
        sleep(0.1);
        sock.sendto(b"connect", addr)
        i += 1
        if time() - last > 1:
                print("> Send {} packages per second to {}:{}".format(i, addr[0], addr[1]))
                i = 0
                last = time()
```

**Ну и наконец сам вопрос**
Каким образом сервер отправляет мне пакеты, если у меня нет выделенного IP? 
Почему сервер `TCP` / `HTTP` без выделенного не видно из интернета, а голый `UDP` каким-то образом принимает пакеты из интернета на свой IP и свой какой-то случайный порт? И почему `socket.bind` не работает если я хочу принимать пакеты на определенный порт?

Comment: На роутере провайдера стоит NAT, который запоминает соответствие между своим внешним IP и вашим внутренним IP для нужного UDP-порта

Comment: @anreymal 
Хорошо, но как это происходит?
Допустим, я отправляю пакет на сервер и скажем, роутер провайдера уже запомнил это соответствие. Я выключаю клиент, (Сервер все еще отправляет пакеты в моем направлении), убираю отправку первого сообщения и сразу ожидаю сообщения от сервера и как результат это не работает. В таком случае, роутер провайдера как-то понял, что пора забыть это соответствие, как он это понял?

Comment: По таймауту, после нескольких минут бездействия. Если клиент перезапускается, то после перезапуска он возьмёт себе другой UDP-порт и без отправки первого сообщения соответствие в NAT не появится, оттого и не работает

Comment: Можно попробовать в клиенте сделать `sock.bind('ip компа посмотреть в настройках сети', любой_udp_port)` — тогда при перезапуске этот самый UDP-порт не будет меняться и всё будет работать (но сам я не пробовал и точно не уверен)

Comment: @anreymal А на уровень ниже, как это реализовано? Провайдер просто видит, что я с порта N отправляю сообщение в сеть и все? Или я могу как-то попросить провайдера создать связь?

Comment: @andreymal Я пробовал, в теле вопроса я описал, что Windows выбрасывает `OSError: Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен`

Comment: Просто видит да. Технически, любой нормальный роутер имеет возможность ручного проброса портов, но скорее всего провайдер не захочет возиться с вашими хотелками

Comment: Если Windows выбрасывает, то значит наверное вы написали какой-то не тот IP. Если у вас дома есть домашний роутер, то IP компа скорее всего будет иметь вид 192.168.x.x

Comment: @andreymal IP в локальной сети я тоже пробовал, но тогда из интернета ко мне не попасть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам уже сказал @andreymal, у провайдера работает [**NAT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2663). У провайдера есть выделенный адрес. **NAT** выполняет сопоставление **`inner_host:inner_port` -> `outer_port`**, где **inner_host** и **inner_port** это адрес и порт хоста в локальной сети провайдера (читайте, ваш локальный адрес), а **outer_port** это порт, торчащий в интернеты.

---

Внутри локальной сети провайдера Ваш компьютер имеет какой-то адрес **A** (например, `192.168.0.103`). Когда Вы отправляете какой-то пакетик, то Вы обязательно отправляете его с какого-то порта **P**. Пункт назначения пакетика это тоже какой-то ip и порт.

**NAT** видит, что с локального адреса **A** и порта **P** отправлен запрос, выбирает какой-то свободный порт **Q**, торчащий в интернеты и запоминает, что за внешним портом **Q** стоят  внутренний адрес **A** и порт **P** (**`A:P` -> `Q`**).

Т.е. по факту удалённый хост получает пакетик, у которого в `source_ip` находится внешний адрес провайдера, а в `source_port` внешний порт **Q**, с которого провайдер отправил Ваш пакетик.

В дальнейшем, когда *провайдер* будет получать пакетики на порт **Q** (а именно на него будут отвечать Вам удалённые хосты, т.к. они получили пакетик с этого порта), **NAT** будет знать, что этот пакетик предназначен для Вашего хоста (**A:P**) и будет отправлять пакетики с порта **Q** к Вам.

---

Есть такая штука, как проброс портов. Это то же самое, что жёстко захардкодить, что пакетики, пришедшие на порт **Q** всегда предназначены для внутреннего хоста **A:P**, но, как Вам опять-таки уже сказали, провайдер, скорее всего, не захочет заморачиваться с этим.